# Helping the GC in mono droid using mvvmCross

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am working with mono droid, using the mvvmcross framework provided by slodge. However I am having some memory issues. I am disposing bitmaps in the activities ondestroy methods and I am wondering if it is possible to help the GC collecting unused objects of viewmodels. If you try setting the viewmodel in the activity to null it all goes to hell and it is clearly not the right way to go.

Do you guys have any suggestions to an approach?

Regards

Comment: I had a similar issue where the objects were just not being released by the GC fast enough. I added "GC.Collect()" in OnDestroy and it started cleaning up properly. Even when all my images were in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mvx framework tries to ensure that the activity owns the viewmodel.

So in theory, after your activity has being destroyed, then the gc should be able to collect all of your c# objects - the activity, the views it owns, the view model and the objects it owns.

Where i've seen this this go wrong is where any 'global' or singleton object owns a reference to a view or viewmodel object. For example:

- if a view registers itself with a singleton - eg an http image loader - and then that singleton keeps a reference to the view, preventing it from being garbage collected.
- if a viewmodel subscribes to an event on a central service (often a singleton) and doesn't unsubscribe from it - then in this situation, the viewmodel can't be garbage collected (and often this also prevents other objects being collected too)

Generally both these types of errors can be solved by performing cleanup actions on activity destroy. However, other approaches are also available - eg for event subscriptions you can try using weak references (this is an approach taken on other platforms too - eg mvvm light's messenger)

From experience, the areas where leaks are most noticeable are around 'big objects' like images - their size helps them become noticeable. However, the real challenge on monodroid is identifying where the leaks are - fixing them is generally comparatively easy.

Sadly, there isn't currently a memory profiler available for droid. If you are cross-compiling to wp7, then certainly for viewmodel objects/leaks you can use its memory profiler. If not, then the way I generally try to solve memory leaks is to amplify them - try writing a sample that rapidly reproduces them - eg by adding large byte[] members to data elements or by rapidly repeating actions. Once you have the leak easily reproduced, then you can try to find the leaks by placing trace statements in finalizers, in event remove handlers, etc.